# How to call non static method in class using __callStatic [without errors]

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with one non-static method `function Tire(){}` like this

```
class Car{
  function Tire(){}  
   static function __callStatic($func, $arg){
      if(method_exists(__CLASS__, $func)){
          return self::$func(); 
       }
   }
}
```

I am trying to call it statically as

```
Car::Tire()
```

But, I get this error.

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Car::Tire() should not be called statically
```

Comment: Why can't you just make the method static?

Comment: @MisterDood Because, I need to know if there is other way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you meant to write `Car::Tire()` ?

Comment: You can not call a non-static function from a static context. Static context doesn't have any object to operate with. If you would even be able to call that non-static function, how would it operate if the object does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Writing `return self::$func();` actually runs the `$func` statically and returns it result. You can't run a non-static function statically — thus, the error message.

You can not call a non-static function from a static context. Static context doesn't have any object to operate with. If you would even be able to call that non-static function, how would it operate if the object does not exist?

Comment: i think you have missed the fact, that I am trying to call an existing function.

Comment: You can not call an existing non-static function in static way or from a static context